# How do I use heredoc in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, heredoc

How do I use heredoc in a Makefile?
This Makefile is not functional:

```
EXECUTABLE=server

build: 
     docker build -t $(EXECUTABLE) - << EOF \
         FROM scratch \
         ADD bin/$(EXECUTABLE) /bin/$(EXECUTABLE) \
         CMD ["/bin/$(EXECUTABLE)"] \
     EOF
```

Comment: What is the simplest docker command that works on the command line, but doesn't work when you put it in a makefile?

Comment: Don't try. Create a shell script wrapper around the command and call that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heredoc in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873025/heredoc-in-a-makefile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like going over a file using heredocs inside a Makefile solves half of the problem:

```
build: Dockerfile
    docker build -t $(EXECUTABLE) .
    rm Dockerfile

.ONESHELL:
Dockerfile: 
    cat <<- EOF > $@
        FROM scratch
        ADD bin/$(EXECUTABLE) /bin/$(EXECUTABLE)
        CMD ["/bin/$(EXECUTABLE)"]
    EOF
```

Still, it would be nice to have it all inline.